# Undefined en php con ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css, ajax

La consola me muestra que la variable no se ha definido 'undefined'
mi js

```
function UpdateUser(str){
var id = str;
var name = $('#nm-'+str).val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "app/bin/adduser.php?p=update",
    data: "id="+id+"&nm="+name,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(name);
        console.log(id);
        viewUser();
    }
})}
```

los input para enviar los datos

```
 <div class="modal-body">
                  <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $user->id; ?>" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nm">Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-ivss" id="nm-<?php echo $user->name; ?>" value="<?php echo $user->name; ?>">
                    </div>
```

Donde recibo los datos

```
elseif ($page == 'update'){
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['nm'];
echo $name;
echo $id;
```

P.D: cabe destacar que me recibe el id mas no el name

Comment: quien llama `UpdateUser` el parametro enviado es el mismo que le da el nombre al input ? `nm-{{variable}}`

Comment: Todas las variables te dan undifinied?

Comment: no, solo la de name

Answer (score 0):

Mira, eso que concatenas en una sola linea al momento de enviar datos mejor envia cada dato en su respectiva variable, prueba esto para tu ajax

```
function UpdateUser(str){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "app/bin/adduser.php?p=update",
        dataType : "json",
        data: {
              Update:{
                  id: $('#idUsuario').val(),
                  nombre: $('#nombreUsuario').val()
              },
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(name);
            console.log(id);
            viewUser();
        }
    })}
```

En el caso de tu formulario, no hay necesidad de hacerlo como lo haces, mejor verifica que se envien los datos y que sea un codigo convencional pero funcional para evitar eso de las concatenaciones, etc.
en lugar del que tienes y si gustas puedes probar esto...

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" id="idUsuario" value="<?php echo $user->id; ?>" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nm">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-ivss" id="nombreUsuario" value="<?php echo $user->name; ?>">
        </div>
</div>
```

y al final lo mandas a llamar de la siguiente manera..

```
elseif ($page == 'update'){
$id = $_POST['Update']['id'];
$name = $_POST['Update']['nombre'];
echo $name;
echo $id;
```

Bueno, solo es mi opinion, puedes tomar ese ejemplo y probarlo en tu sistema si es de tu agrado.. espero poderte haber ayudado..
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El problema viene  en que en el html al input name lo defines como `"nm-<?php echo user->name;?>"` y en el js en str envias el id por eso mismo te tira el undefined e intentas acceder al name con este id, para q te funcione deberias modificar el input name `"nm-<?php echo user->id;?>"` para q te funcione.
**Procedo a darte una breve explicación paso a paso del significado de lo que estas intentando hacer y cual seria la forma correcta de expresarlo**
1-  type: "POST" quiere decir que el tipo de petición es mediante POST por lo tanto la forma correcta de realizar la petición es la siguiente:

```
function UpdateUser(str){

$.ajax({
    // especifica si será una petición POST o GET
    type: "POST",
    //URL de la petición
    url: "app/bin/adduser.php",
    // el tipo de información que se espera de respuesta
    dataType : "json",
    // la información a enviar
    // (esta puede ser una cadena de datos)
    data: {
              p:'update'
              id: id,
              nm:name

    }....
```

2 `dataType:'json'` indica que la respuesta del ajax debe ser de este tipo por lo tanto desde php retornamos el resultado `json_encode($array)`:

```
    $page = $_POST['p'];
    elseif ($page == 'update'){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['nombre'];
    $array = array(
    "name"    => $name,
    "address"  => $id,
   );
   //Retorna la representación JSON del valor dado
   echo json_encode($array);
```

3- por ultimo en el la función que definimos en el success obtenemos lo que nos manda el php  y podemos acceder al id y name de esta forma:

```
 // código a ejecutar si la petición es satisfactoria;
// la respuesta es pasada como argumento a la función
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.name);
    console.log(data.id);
    viewUser();
}
```

Comment: Pude ver el error del undefined,y te lo dejo en mi respuesta,cual quier duda q tengas avisame

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que cambiarlo aqui:

```
 <div class="modal-body">
                  <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $user->id; ?>" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nm">Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-ivss" id="nm-<?php echo $user->name; ?>" value="<?php echo $user->name; ?>">
                    </div>
```

Cuando pasas el `str` por parametro estas pasando el ID numerico que es el que te funciona, pues en el input tenias que tambien poner ese `$user->id` en el `id="nm-<?php echo $user->name; ?>"`, si le pones `$user->name` nunca te recogera ese valor, tiene que ser  `$user->id` quedando asi `<input type="text" class="form-ivss" id="nm-<?php echo $user->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $user->name; ?>">`